# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to activate <myWSP> Farm feature

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I'm having issues deploying a wsp component, from my solution in VS2015, to my Sharepoint 2016 site.  I get the error in the title.

However, when I look in Sharepoint 2016 Central Administration -> System Settings -> Farm Management -> Manage Farm solutions -> , it shows that it is deployed.  I retracted myWSP and began the process again, thinking it may be sharepoint not updating and the same thing happen ie not deploying from VS2015 but having status 'Deployed' in central administrator.

Looking at Sharepoint Designer, the files in myWSP are not there so it follows that it did not deploy.  So why does central administration show that it is?

My basic problem is I can't deploy from visual studio.  I have deployed from this before but it's not deploying now.  I tried recycling services in IIS and deploying from SharePoint 2016 Management Shell:

```
Install-SPSolution -identity myWSP.wsp -GACDeployment
```

Nothing I've tried is working.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try to install the feature manually with Install-SPFeature. You could use the force command if nothing else helps. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spfeature?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue, go Sharepoint 2016 Central Administration -> System Settings -> Farm Management -> Manage Farm solutions, then click on the individual solution, retract the solution and remove the solution.

After this do a fresh deployment from Visual Studio.

More references:

[Create SharePoint Project And Deployment Steps Using Visual Studio 2015.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-sharepoint-project-and-deployment-steps-using-visual-studio-2015/)

[SharePoint 2010 Troubleshooting: Error occurred in deployment step Activate Features.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28871.sharepoint-2010-troubleshooting-error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features.aspx)